# Filebeat - Certain fields in “drop_fields” are not dropped

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I'm trying to drop certain fields using filebeat's `drop_fields` processor, so that they will not be indexed to my Elasticsearch. I'm using version 8.8.0 for both filebeat and elasticsearch.

Most of the fields specified in the `drop_fields` array are dropped, but a few are not, e.g. `source.geo.city_name`, `destination.geo.location.lon`, and `network.direction`. Except for `network.direction`, all the field names that were dropped only have one period in them, e.g. `abc.def`.

A portion of the relevant configuration in `filebeat.yml` is

```
processors:
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["destination.bytes", "destination.geo.location.lon", "ecs.version", "source.bytes", "source.geo.city_name", "network.direction", "source.packets"]
```

Why are some of these fields not dropped?

Comment: Hey Rayne, can you please share the full filebeat.yml and the `GET index` API call output?

Maybe there is an if condition or an ingest pipeline or a strict mapping or more :) I will check for you

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you are looking for? I'm not able to share the full filebeat.yml nor the `GET index` API call output, as my ES cluster is on a separate network, and I would have to manually type out everything. I did not specify an ingest pipeline or any if condition in filebeat.yml, but the `source.geo.*` and `destination.geo.*` are the IP geoloc enriched fields from Maxmind. The fields that were not dropped were mapped as `keyword`, except for the lat/lon fields, which were mapped to `float`. `drop_fields` is the only processor.

Comment: Just to add, the IP geoloc is based on [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-geoip.html), but using an offline Maxmind database. I did not explicitly specify any geoip pipeline in filebeat.yml. I only had to put the database files in the necessary location and configure ES to not [download updates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geoip-processor.html#manually-update-geoip-databases) and the geoloc enrichment was done automatically.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it can be because of filebeat geoip ingest pipeline. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-geoip.html

Comment: If `source.ip` field exist it will generate `source.geo` field during index time. You can't drop the `source.geo` field in filebeat but in elasticsearch because the field is not yet exist. The `source.geo` field will be populated after filebeat send the data to elasticsearch. This is the reason why some of `drop_fields` processor won't work.

* To remove `source.geo` field you can edit the `geoip-info` ingest pipeline and use remove processor.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/remove-processor.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the remove processor then.

Comment: Yes, it's probably works :) let me know the result